# Expected number of errors in a magazine page

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The expected number of typographic errors in a page of a certain magazine is 2.What is the probability that an article of 10 pages has 2 errors?

**My attempt:** I thought that if $X$ is the r.v that counts the numbers of errors in this article, then it has distribution $Poisson(20)$, but the answer says it has distribution $Poisson(2)$. I don't understand why, since I thought we should consider that the errors per page are independent and then the expected number of errors in $10$ pages is $20$

Thanks!

Comment: If we use the usual Poisson distribution model, and the wording is exactly as you put it, you are right, the number of errors in $10$ pages has Poisson distribution mean (parameter) $20$.

Comment: @Andre, Is it then $P(Z = 1) = \frac{e^{-20}.20^1}{1!}$ that has been asked?

Comment: As the question is currently put, if $Z$ is the number of errors in the article, we are asked for $\Pr(Z=2)$. Which is tiny.

Comment: Thanks for both of you, I agree with you, probably the answer is wrong.